# Django, form is_valid() is always false

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and have some troubles with forms. I try to create a simple form where I type a name and show it on another page. But is_valid() always returns false. Please, help me to find my error

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    user=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
def order(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/order.html', {})


def contact(request):
    username='not logged'

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form=OrderForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
        else:
            username='not worked'
    else:
        form=OrderForm()

    return render(request, 'myapp/contacts.html', {'username':username})
```

**order.html**

```
<form name = "form" action = "{% url 'contact' %}" method = "POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**contacts.html**

```
You are : <strong>{{ username }}</strong>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form control has the name `username` in HTML, while your form's field is named `user` in Django. Thus, nothing is set in the form field.

Normally you'd put the form into the context and then render it either as `{{ form }}` or the like, or render each field, rather than build your own form controls. The docs show how: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates

Comment: yes, I renamed 'user' to 'username' and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## views.py

```
    from forms import OrderForm
    def order(request):
        form = OrderForm()
        return render(request, 'myapp/order.html', {"form" : form})
```

## order.html

```
<form name = "form" action = "{% url 'contact' %}" method = "POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

At the time of rendering  template **{{form.as_p}}**  looks like

```
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="100" required /></p>
```